# Does the vacuum have a temperature?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, temperature, vacuum

Since the vacuum polarisation leads to the appearance of particle antiparticle pairs, which have a kinetic energy, can therefore to the vacuum a temperature be attributed?
If yes what is the Value of the temperature of the vacuum?

Answer (score 1):

'Temperature is a statistical quantity.' If you have any quantum system, described by a basis of states $|0\rangle, |1\rangle, |2\rangle,\dots$, where each state has energy given by $E_0, E_1, \dots$, then the system at a temperature $T$ is described by the thermal state
$$\rho = \frac{1}{Z}\sum_i e^{-\frac{E_i}{k_BT}} |i\rangle \langle i|$$
In other words, temperature is not associated to a single state, but rather to a certain statistical collection of states. The vacuum, (being a single pure state), in some sense has no notion of temperature.

The vacuum is however the state with the lowest energy, so you can call it the thermal state where $T = 0$. The preceding paragraph was really just to push forward the point that generically, temperature implies you are not in a pure state

I recognize maybe a lot of these terms may be unfamiliar, so I'll leave some links

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_quantum_field_theory